# How to show element near to the clicked tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have to show color-picker to let change the color of desired property . Everything is working fine but is there a way to show near the tag where user click  the property .

Like when user click border property than picker show up near border and if user click background than it is shown near background .

> Is it possible using single function or I have to have separate functions and separate `input`

I have used separate color-picker to show on click :

```js
var spanTag = document.querySelectorAll("span");
var inputTag = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (let i = 0; i < spanTag.length; i++) {
  spanTag[i].addEventListener('click', funcRun)


  function funcRun() {
    if (i == 0) {
      inputTag[i].style.display = "block";
      inputTag[i+1].style.display = "none";
    } else if (i == 1) {
      inputTag[i].style.display = "block";
      inputTag[i-1].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Border</h3>
  <span>borderColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="borderColor">
  <h3>Background</h3>
  <span>backgroundColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="backgroundColor">
</div>
```

Thanks for help in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with moving `<input type="color">` near the `<span>`

> but it is without guarantees, and there are still problems here, for example in case of cancellation. The colors pickers of the different types of browsers do not make friends with each other, and even less with JS code

```js
const colorChooser = document.querySelector('#color-chooser')

colorChooser.onclick=_=>
  {
  colorChooser.disabled = true
  colorChooser.ref      = null
  }
colorChooser.onchange=_=>
  {
  colorChooser.sp.style.setProperty('--onColor', colorChooser.value)
  colorChooser.classList.add('noDisplay')
  colorChooser.disabled = false
  }
document.querySelectorAll("span.colorChoose").forEach( sp =>
  {
  let spPos = { top: (sp.offsetTop -10) + 'px' , left: (sp.offsetLeft + sp.offsetWidth +10)+'px' }

  sp.onclick =_=>
    {
    if (!colorChooser.classList.toggle('noDisplay', colorChooser.ref===sp.id))
      {
      colorChooser.value      = sp.style.getPropertyValue('--onColor')
      colorChooser.style.top  = spPos.top
      colorChooser.style.left = spPos.left
      colorChooser.ref        = sp.id
      colorChooser.sp         = sp
      }
    else
      { 
      colorChooser.ref      = null
      colorChooser.disabled = false
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
span.colorChoose {
  cursor        : pointer;
  border-bottom : 3px solid var(--myColor)
  }
span.colorChoose:before {
  content      : ' ';
  display      : inline-block;
  width        : .9em;
  height       : .9em;
  border       : 1px solid black;
  margin-right : .2em;
  background   : var(--onColor);
  }
#color-chooser {
  position   : absolute;
  top        : 0;
  left       : 0;
  }
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color-chooser" value="" class="noDisplay">
 
<div>
  <h3>Border</h3>
  <span id="border-id-ref" class="colorChoose" style="--onColor:#ff0000">borderColor</span>
 
  <h3>Background</h3>
  <span id="bg-id-ref"  class="colorChoose" style="--onColor:#00ff00">backgroundColor</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't get your question wrong  :-D

```js
var spanTag = document.querySelectorAll("span");
var inputTag = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (let i = 0; i < spanTag.length; i++) {
  spanTag[i].addEventListener('click', funcRun)


  function funcRun() {
    if (i == 0) {
      inputTag[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      inputTag[i+1].style.display = "none";
    } else if (i == 1) {
      inputTag[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      inputTag[i-1].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Border</h3>
  <span>borderColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="borderColor">
  <h3>Background</h3>
  <span>backgroundColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="backgroundColor">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this is not I wanted to do . It is that, let say there is only 1 `input` in html now when user clicks on 1st `span` than that `input` display near that tag and if it is 2nd `span` tag than `input` is displayed near that

Answer (score 1):

that ?

I think you are looking for [element.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) . usage :

```js
 
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach( sp =>
  {
  let nextEl = sp.nextElementSibling
  sp.onclick      =_=> nextEl.classList.toggle('noDisplay')
  nextEl.onclick  =_=> nextEl.classList.add('noDisplay')
  nextEl.onchange =_=> sp.style.setProperty('--myColor', nextEl.value)
  })
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
  }
span {
  --myColor     : black;
  cursor        : pointer;
  border-bottom : 3px solid var(--myColor)
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Border</h3>
  <span>borderColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="borderColor" class="noDisplay">
  <h3>Background</h3>
  <span>backgroundColor</span>
  <input type="color" id="backgroundColor" class="noDisplay">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help , Is the same behavior possible with single `input` such that single `input` will position next to the clicked element . And can you tell about `=_=>`

Comment: Is it possible with only **JS** or have to use a extension for that

Comment: @Rana I'm not sure this is actually feasible, because the picker window (operated by the color input) is a black box. I have to try it out, it can't take time

Comment: @Rana to get element id simply `sp.id` or `nextEl.id`,; doc on [`element.classList.toogle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) and see left column for others methods

Comment: @Rana `element.textContent = element.className` give all class values on referenced element

Comment: @Rana that's too much, you should instead open a new question with this one and the following ones